# Can propagate models to components but not to sap.ui.jsfragment

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5

My controls inside my fragment have access to models that are bound to

```
sap.ui.getCore();
```

but not to models set to the component from which I am calling the fragment. The problem seems to be that my fragment has no parent, so the models cannot be propagated.

For components, I know you can simply set propagation in the componentContainer

```
        url: "resources/components/" + sPath,
            name: "components." + sPath.replace("/", "."),
            id: "components." + +sPath.replace("/", "."),
            propagateModel: true
          });
```

Is there such a method for my fragments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your fragment to the view by calling view.addDependent(fragment). In this case models known to the view will be available in the fragment.

Comment: Hi Matbtt, if I try this I get the following error in my console:
`Uncaught Error: "ManagedObject sap.ui.core.Fragment#__fragment126" is not valid for aggregation "dependents" of Element sap.ui.core.mvc.JSView#components.my.path.views.Main`.

If I try to add a control inside of my fragment directly, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setBindingContext' of undefined`.

Comment: Can you add an example, how you include the fragment?

Comment: I fiddled around a bit and it works, I think the errors I received were thanks to something else in my code. This is exactly the function I was looking for!